# Pictures of the Prince Edward Islands

Tags: images, wikimedia-commons

I am looking for open pictures of any of the Prince Edward Islands (for instance Marion Island).

Not satellite or maps: rather landscapes or really any picture taken from a boat or from the ground.

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Prince_Edward_Islands does not have any match.
*(Fairy Prion with egg.jpg is probably an error and actually from Macquarie Island, currently under discussion)*

The pictures must have a license compatible with Wikimedia Commons (CC-BY-SA, GFDL or more permissive).